# Sending emails on behalf of someone using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, email, nodemailer, spf, dkim

I'm trying to send an email on behalf of my user using `nodemailer` but all my emails are being rejected.

My transporter works for normal use-cases where I'm sending from my own domain:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'emailhost.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {...},
    dkim: {
      domainName: <domainname>,
      keySelector: <keyselector>,
      privateKey: <privatekey>,
    },
  });

transporter.sendMail({
  subject: "Shop subject",
  from: `kyle@mydomain.com`,
  to: <customerEmail>,
  replyTo: <shopEmail>,
  html: "<div>my user message</div>",
})
```

But when I try to send on behalf of my user it doesn't work:

```
transporter.sendMail({
  subject: "Shop subject",
  from: `shop@exampleshop.com`,
  to: <customerEmail>,
  // sender: `kyle@mydomain.com` <-- Also tried adding this field,
  replyTo: `shop@exampleshop.com`,
  html: "<div>my user message</div>",
})

>> "Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 553 <shop@exampleshop.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user kyle@mydomain.com"
```

I figured if I set a DKIM DNS record and an SPF record on `exampleshop.com` it would mean I could send emails on behalf of the domain but still no luck.

```
Type: TXT Record 
Host: @ 
Value: v=spf1 include:spf.emailhost.com ~all

// Also tried adding this record in place of the one above
Type: TXT Record 
Host: @ 
Value: v=spf1 include:spf.mydomain.com ~all

Type: TXT Record 
Host: default._domainkey
Value: v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=<DKIM DNS record from namecheap>
```

It's also been over an hour since I've updated the DNS records, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It’s your mail server giving that response, and I doubt that has got as far as checking SPF. It will be down to your mail server config.

Comment: So, I send the email using my private DKIM/auth, the mail server (privateemail from namecheap) receives the email and sees a different "from" domain and doesn't check the SPF records of the other domain so it rejects the email? Is this roughly what's happening?

Comment: Yes, that’s about it. It’s a very common restriction, for example gmail does it.

Answer (score 2):

try using the `envelope` for this.  as i understand it, **"envelope"** values are like whats written on the outside of a physical piece of mail. it tells the post office where to actually send (or return) the message.  the **"header from"**, on the other hand, is like when you re-write your address at the top of the piece of paper that comes inside the envelope.  it doesn't do anything but it looks nice.

```
header_from = "it-just-looks-like-its-from-me@asdf.com"
envelope_from = "im-actually-doing-the-sending@asdf.com"
to = 'pick-me@asdf.com'

var mailOptions = {
  from: header_from,
  to: to,
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!',
  envelope: {
      from: envelope_from,
      to: to,
  }
};
```

https://nodemailer.com/smtp/envelope/